# iterating through an abject array

Tags: jquery, object, each

I need help iterating though an array of objects.
I can successfully iterate though variable 'props' but I can't with 'propsObjs'.

```
var props = {
    'dog':'true',
    'cat':'true',
    'mouse':'true'
};

var propsObjs = [
    {name:'dog', state:'true'},
    {name:'cat', state:'true'},
    {name:'mouse', state:'true'}
];

$.each(propsObjs, function (key, value) {
    $('#' + key + '-btn').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('inactive-props');
    $('.' + key + ' ').toggleClass('hide');
});
});
```

Here is a link to a prototype:
http://jsfiddle.net/readrefuse73/dZysP/10/

Comment: Why do you need to use an array?  If it's working with the object then just use that.

Comment: I am building a more complicated prototype which I am building up in stages. So the next stage in complexity is to work with a more complicated vraiable/array. Eventually I would like to work with a array of objects like this one:

{ id: 0, path: 'http://placehold.it/25x25', tags: ['dog','cat'] }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one `propsObjs` is an array of `object`.

So try accessing object property `name` will help you

```
$.each(propsObjs, function (index, obj) {
    $('#' + obj.name+ '-btn').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('inactive-props');
    $('.' + obj.name+ ' ').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the delegate function `$.each` iterates over has `index` and `value` parameters. Therefore in your example `key` is an integer containing the index of the iteration, and `value` is the object contained in the array. What you need is something more like this:

```
$.each(propsObjs, function (index, value) {
    var key = value.name;
    $('#' + key + '-btn').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('inactive-props');
    $('.' + key).toggleClass('hide');
});
```